# unable to redirect data by using awk or cat

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, sh

I am using AIX for following code:

```
#!/bin/sh
cat ip.txt | awk -F ' ' '{print $2,$1}' >op.txt
```

or

```
awk -F ' ' '{print $2,$1}' ip.txt > op2.txt
```

It is generating an unknown file named "oxb1du". 
Aslo, I can see file `op2.txt` after `ls -ltr` but it does not contain any data.

```
I/P file:
    name 1
    info 21
    city 28
    pin  31
    state 34
```

Comment: What does `cat -A ip.txt` show?

Comment: @OP You seem to have misunderstood something.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for:

```
cat ip.txt | awk '{print $2,$1}' > op.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably have binary characters in your file.  Try cleaning it first.

```
tr -cd '[:graph:]\n\t ' <"$file" >$TEMP_FILE && mv $TEMP_FILE "$file"
```

dos2unix and other programs may work, but I've had issues with dos2unix only removing carriage returns, and not other garbage so I've given you the above (obviously assign or replace the variables).  Then just use:

```
awk -F" " '{print $2,$1}' ip.txt > op2.txt
```

I only changed the quotes for readability-- having them hanging away from the -F, and before other single quotes looks wonky.  This way is quicker to read.